# $AB=0$ where $A$ and $B$ are positive semidefinite. What can we say about $A$ and $B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

Suppose that $A,B$ are non-zero, positive semidefinite, $n \times n$ real matrices and that $AB=0$. What can we say about $A$ and $B$?

More precisely, given some $A\neq 0$ non-zero, positive semidefinite, $n \times n$ real matrix. What are the minimal set of conditions on a non-zero, positive semidefinite, $n \times n$ real matrix $B$ to guarantee that $AB \neq0$?

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: $A,B$ are symmetric.

Comment: Are the matrices symmetric?

Comment: yes! I will add this

Comment: They commute, so they share eigenvectors.  The sum of their ranks must be at most $n$.

Comment: There exists an invertible matrix $M = [M_1 \ \ M_2\ \ M_3]$ (where $M_3$ might have zero columns) such that $A = M_1M_1^T$ and $B = M_2M_2^T$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your comments? I am particularly interested in answering the second question, ie guaranteeing $AB \neq 0$

Comment: BTW, the usual term is positive semidefinite.

Comment: Is it a matrix of positive entries and that is equal to its conjugate transpose?

Comment: @CharlieChang: Symmetric means equal to its transpose (but then, this is about real matrices, so transpose and conjugate transpose agree). Positive semidefinite then means that it has no negative eigenvalue (I'm not sure how the exact definition is for non-symmetric matrices, but that doesn't matter here anyway). Note that this isn't the same as having only positive entries; for example, $$\pmatrix{1&-1\\-1&1}$$ is positive semidefinite but has negative entries, while $$\pmatrix{1&2\\2&1}$$ has only positive entries but is not positive semidefinite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A,B\neq0$ then $AB=0$ if and only if $A\bot B$. This also means that the vectors of $A,B$ each span some subspace in $\mathbb{R}^n$, they span a disjoint space, and that $Span\{A\}\cup Span\{B\} = \mathbb{R}^n$. We also conclude that the dimension of the subspaces $dim_A+dim_B = n$.

Therefore if you have a given matrix $A$, it's sufficient to set $B$ such that $Span\{A\}\cap Span\{B\}\neq \emptyset$.

Comment: You cannot conclude that the union of the spans is all of $\mathbb R^n$. As simple counterexample, take $n>2$, $A$ is the orthogonal projector on the first dimension, and $B$ is the orthogonal projector on the second dimension.